# What to add in requirements file

Tags: python, pip, deprecated, requirements.txt

I want to add python cloudant to a project (the new version not the deprecated)
https://github.com/cloudant/python-cloudant

Their instructions:

for newest:

```
pip install --pre cloudant
```

for deprecated:

```
pip install cloudant
```

The project I am doing uses a requirements.txt file.

Using pip install --pre cloudant on my local computer works fine, but when pushing to the cloud I require to add it to the requirements.

Now, if I add

```
cloudant
```

to the requirements I guess it would install the deprecated (like on my pc)

But if I write:

```
--pre cloudant
```

It makes an error:

```
ERRpip: error: no such option: --pre
```

Anyone that can help me on how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to upgrade `pip` to have the `--pre` option - it was [introduced in pip 1.4](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/).

`--pre` in requirements files support [was added in pip 8.0.0](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1273).